# How to deal with crawler and outdated assets?

Tags: yii2, resources, web-crawler

I've got the following error with my web application:

```
2017-12-02 22:32:39
[10.133.0.13][-][-][error][yii\web\HttpException:404]
yii\base\InvalidRouteException: Unable to resolve the request
"assets/7adcf7ba/site.css". in
/var/www/html/my-website/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php:537
```

It was caused by the [web crawler of Google](http://www.google.com/bot.html) as I see it in HTTP_USER_AGENT. The folder `7adcf7ba` does not exist (anymore), so I think the crawler uses cached data somehow.

How can I prevent that the crawler tries to access this outdated resource file and use the current one?

I don't want a solution with the [Google's Search Console](http://google.com/webmasters/tools), since it isn't the only web crawler, of course, and I don't want to maintain several crawlers.

Can I use the robots.txt? Meta tags? Special attributes? How should I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You must set to TRUE the `$forceCopy` property of [yii\web\AssetManager](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-assetmanager.html):

```
'components' => [
    ...
    'assetManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\AssetManager',
        'forceCopy' => true,
    ],
    ...
],
```

"*You may want to set this to be true during the development stage to make sure the published directory is always up-to-date. Do not set this to true on production servers as it will significantly degrade the performance.*" from: [$forceCopy](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-assetmanager.html#$forceCopy-detail)

**[Edit]**

*More explanations are required*

*"A crawler (also called a spider or robot), is a software that analyzes the data of a network in a methodical and automatic way, usually on behalf of a search engine. Crawlers typically acquire a textual copy of all the documents visited and insert them into an index.
An extremely common use of crawlers is on the Web. On the Web, the crawler relies on a list of URLs to be visited provided by the search engine (which initially is based on the addresses suggested by users or on a list pre-filled by the programmers themselves ). When analyzing a URL, it identifies all the hyperlinks in the document and adds them to the list of URLs to visit. The process can be concluded manually or after a certain number of links has been followed. In addition, Internet crawlers have the option to be directed by the "robots.txt" file located in the root of the site. Within this file, you can indicate which pages should not be analyzed. The crawler has the right to follow the advice, but not the obligation."* from: [Web crawler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler)

So you can configure robots.txt for allow or not a crawler to indexing specific pages in his search engine but not for avoid assets errors. The publication of the assets is another thing.

Comment: That cannot be the answer. More explanation is required. _Do not set this to true on production servers_ ... I won't set it true.

Comment: You've get an error becouse the assets are not published correctly becousr you deleted it.If you want to avoid that error you need to force copy. Crawler of google is just for indexing a page in the search engine.

Comment: Do not set this to true on production becouse in a prod env the source assets are published one time and they must not be changed except by a new release